# FastReport Delphi Preview fails when printing in a loop

Tags: printing, reporting, delphi

I have a function that prints a report for each selected item in a grid.
If I use preview without prepare it works but if I use prepare only the first report is printed. All the rest gives an empty report.

I create the report dynamically also the dataset is created dynamically. All components are freed at the end and recreated at the next report.

If I print all items one by one it works.

What happens in the prepare function, what can I do to avoid this?
I use FR5 and Delphi XE6 on windows10

Comment: There is an edit attempt from another user with the name "larand". The owner can edit their question freely. If you accidentally created two accounts, check [this link](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts). Those links may be useful: `https://superuser.com/users/721886/larand54` and `https://superuser.com/users/721962/larand`.

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User! We are always glad to help, but you apparently have two Super User accounts: [this one](https://superuser.com/users/721886/larand54) and [this one](https://superuser.com/users/721962/larand). Please take the time to utilize the following Help Center tutorial and ask the Super User staff to merge your accounts: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: Create a small demo project with error based on standart Delphi's components and local database like MSAccess database and attach it here or send it to support@fast-report.com

Answer (score 0):

If you create composite report - call TfrxReport.PrepareReport(True) on the first loop, TfrxReport.PrepareReport(False) on the next loops